# A new JSESSIONID is created on every page refresh but not from all browsers

Tags: session, grails, jetty, shiro

I am using Grails 2.4.3 with shiro plugin 1.2.1 on Jetty 9.1.5
The problem is that a new JSESSIONID is generated every time a page is reloaded (Shiro should not do this).

But it gets really strange since this is not always the case:
If I use Chrome, Firefox or IE from a Windows 7 machine, I get the problem.
If I use Chrome or Firefox on a machine with Ubuntu, the behavior is the right one (the JSESSIONID cookie is kept even when the page is reloaded)

I tried to use a different cookie name as someone else suggested in other post but this did not fix the problem; the cookie with the new name was being generated again on every page refresh.

The serverURL I use in my grails application is of the form `http://subdomain2.subdomain1.com` as it is suggested (no slash at the end)

I checked the requests from all the browsers and they all look the same (with the same headers except for the user-agent) so I don't really understand why the server creates a new session with every refresh in some cases and it does not on some others.

I have a HttpSessionListener listener on 'sessionCreated' so I can perfectly see that.
... but I don't understand why and this is driving me nuts.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issues with using Vaadin and shiro. When the webapplication was using the JSESSION in the url, things got messy.

What helped for us is adding this to web.xml, telling the webserver to only use cookies for session id tracking:

```
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>false</http-only>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

Comment: The comment is misleading - this is an session configuration. Refer to [http-only](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) and [secure](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag).